# Does docker-compose support merging extension field environment variables with service declarations?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Using the extension fields feature of Docker Compose 3.4, is it possible to combine a common set of environment variables in array form (or any array) with service-specific declarations? The [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#extension-fields) is unclear as to whether this is supported.

Calling `docker-compose up` on the the following YAML results in `restart`, `entrypoint`, and `volumes` being set in `my-service`, but it seems to replace the `environment` declaration coming from the extension field with the declaration which exists in `my-service`. I would like them merged.

```
version: '3.4'
x-service-config: &service-config
  restart: "on-failure"
  entrypoint: ""
  volumes:
    - "~/.aws:/home/serviceuser/.aws"
  environment:
    - "CommonVar1=foo"
    - "CommonVar2=bar"
services:
  my-service:
    <<: *service-config
    image: my-service:latest
    environment:
      - "ServiceVar1=baz"
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The merge only happens at the top level. If you want to merge a key at a lower level, use a separate template.

---

I've recreated the issue using the following compose file. It uses a public image and runs the `env` command so one can easily follow along without any external dependencies.

Here's a `docker-compose.yml` that works standalone, showing the 'environment' getting merge in:

```
version: '3.4'
x-service-config: &ref
    restart: 'on-failure'
    environment: &env
        'foo': 'bar'
        'bing': 'baz'
services:
    bop:
        image: 'alpine'
        command: 'env'
        <<: *ref
```

Here's the output, showing that the 'environment' key from the anchor is getting copied over:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "merge_default" with the default driver
Creating merge_bop_1 ... done
Attaching to merge_bop_1
bop_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
bop_1  | HOSTNAME=d4122a655e1d
bop_1  | foo=bar
bop_1  | bing=baz
bop_1  | HOME=/root
merge_bop_1 exited with code 0
```

---

Here's the same compose file, but with 'environment' overridden in the 'bop' service definition:

```
version: '3.4'
x-service-config: &ref
    restart: 'on-failure'
    environment: &env
        'foo': 'bar'
        'bing': 'baz'
services:
    bop:
        image: 'alpine'
        command: 'env'
        environment:
            'bat': 'far'
        <<: *ref
```

and the corresponding output, showing *only* `bat=far` and not the other variables:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "merge_default" with the default driver
Creating merge_bop_1 ... done
Attaching to merge_bop_1
bop_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
bop_1  | HOSTNAME=efe76cb7e09d
bop_1  | bat=far
bop_1  | HOME=/root
merge_bop_1 exited with code 0
```

---

The fix is to break this out into two template/anchors as follows:

```
version: '3.4'
x-service-config: &ref
    restart: 'on-failure'
x-environment-config: &env
    'foo': 'bar'
    'bing': 'baz'
services:
    bop:
        image: 'alpine'
        command: 'env'
        environment:
          <<: *env
          'true': 'false'
        <<: *ref
```

and here's the output showing the merged values:

```
$ docker-compose up
Creating network "merge_default" with the default driver
Creating merge_bop_1 ... done
Attaching to merge_bop_1
bop_1  | PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
bop_1  | HOSTNAME=617f90a94a7d
bop_1  | foo=bar
bop_1  | bing=baz
bop_1  | true=false
bop_1  | HOME=/root
merge_bop_1 exited with code 0
```

This works because you're doing the merge at both keys that you want to merge.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you. The one thing this is missing though is that I am attempting to use the list format in my original example, and this does not seem to be supported with YAML merge. https://github.com/yaml/yaml/issues/35

Comment: Reason being, I would like to use a variable in my key declaration, and that doesn't seem to work with the dictionary format.